# How to align the center this menu?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/)

I built this menu CSS code is below ...

**CODE CSS:**

```
.wrapper .content .content-menu {
  width: 91%;
  /*background: #5B626A;*/
  position:fixed;
  z-index:9999;
  left: 4%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="content-menu">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                           //Some CODE HTML
                        </div>
                   </div>
</div>
```

Best HTML code shown on the site ... Can you please tell me how to make this menu is always at the center?
I made a screen print to understand more clearly what they want.

[image]

Comment: You can't lock its position as "fixed" and then expect margins or anything else to work.

Comment: Upon looking at this, you've included the wrong CSS for this element.  You should be concentrating on the UL block.

Comment: do you want the logo in the middle of the page above the vertical line see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` to center it alongside fixed positioning.
Centering elements using margin: 0 auto is for elements in page flow not the fixed positioned, absolute positioned or floated elements

Comment: You could also simply assign `width: 50%` to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the left and right menus 50%, place the logo -half the width to the left with margin place the left meniu half+marginto the right

```
    ul.lang-top.navbar-right {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.lang-top.navbar-right li:first-child > img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-left: -67px;
}

.menu-menu-1-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}

ul#menu-menu-1 {
    float: right;
    margin-right:90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want to achieve?
[image]

I manage to do that by using this code:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu-menu-1-container, .lang-top {
    display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul.lang-top.navbar-right {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.lang-top li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Let me know if you still encountered any problem